# Error calculating mean by input variable in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Using the mtcars dataset in R, I am tying to use the input variable (cyl, am etc...) to calculate the mean mpg by that variable.

My code in the ui.R is like:

```
verbatimTextOutput("Avg_Mileage")
```

My code in the shinServer function in server.R is like:

```
carsdata <- mtcars

output$Avg_Mileage <- renderPrint({aggregate(mpg~input$variable, carsdata,mean)})
```

I have tried to change the code in server.R in various ways. But I keep getting the message about conflicting variable lengths: **"variable lengths differ (found for 'input$variable')**"

I would appreciate any help in trying to see how can this mean mpg by input variable be implemented in Shiny

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out this one.

Changed the server.R to:

```
output$Avg_Mileage <- renderTable({aggregate(as.formula(formulaText()), carsdata,mean)})
```

and ui.R to:

```
tableOutput(outputId = "Avg_Mileage")
```